# how to make only one button highlited when an adapter is used to set the button in the expandablelist view

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an adapter in which i uses the below class

```
private class ViewHolder {
    TextView tvTitle;
    CheckBox cbSelection;
    CheckBox cbFavourite;
    LinearLayout llPassionInterestLayout;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        tvTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_list);
        cbSelection = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cb_selection);
        cbFavourite = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cb_favourite);
        llPassionInterestLayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ll_passion_interest_parent);
    }
}
```

in  my adapter

```
 ViewHolder holder;
 holder.cbFavourite.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                String key = isChecked ? passion.getKey() : null;
                ObjectFactory.getInstance().getNewUserManager(context).setInterestFavourite(key);
```

when set this through adapter in my view I can see 5 buttons (button image is a star with a grey color, when clicked on the button the button image color changes to red). currently when i click on each button, it changes to red color. after clicking all the buttons , every button turns red..

My issue is I need to make only one button selected, ie if when i clicked on the button 1, it turns red. after that if i clicked the button 2 , the button 2 must go red and button 1 should go back to the grey color

How can i do that

Comment: Instead of having checkbox, you can use `radiogroup` with `radiobuttons` and change the button drawable as what you want

Answer (score 0):

Checkbox should be used if you want the user to select multiple options. Whereas 
Radio buttons guarantees a single option among multiple options.
If you want other buttons should turn gray, only selected should turn red Please use RadioButton